# Any way to get a specified magnification effect?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm trying to simulate the magnification of a rifle scope. However, I don't want it to be a random amount, as rifle scopes typically have a set range of magnification (for example anywhere from 6x to 14x).
I've done research prior to posting this, and I know having two UV Spheres scaled down from their poles and at different overall sizes would generate the effect I'm looking for, but is there a way to get a specified setting say like 4x zoom? I'm not looking to get a range to adjust from, just one level of magnification.

Also, if it helps, I'd preferably like to do this in the Cycles rendering engine if at all possible.

I made a rough model of the ACOG 4x rifle scope and studied up on the internal parts. It contains two eyepiece lenses, a roof prism and the objective lens, which I modeled. It works somewhat, most likely because I made the prism too square.

Comment: what do you need the magnification effect for?

Comment: Rending using caustics in blender like you suggest will be verrrry slow.

Comment: Well, I'm attempting to model the actual scope itself, and I want to get as realistic as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend not trying to actually model the lenses to magnify the image, but rather place a camera in front of the scope with a higher *[Focal Length](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Camera#Camera_Settings)*.

Then in the compositer you can add the scope's camera view to the final image.

Comment: I'll try that, but the thing is that I'm actually making a model of a rifle to go along with this as well, so I'm not looking for a camera view through the scope itself.

Comment: @Forged-In-Steel so you are interested in the inside of a scope, and how to model it, not really a image rendered as if looking through it. Is that right?

Comment: @Forged-In-Steel Something more like [this](http://www.opticstalk.com/photoserver/images/photos/2743.jpg) then [this](http://www.omidjahromi.com/Hunting/Shooting/October_2012/Mauser_338_ScopeView_A.jpg)?

Comment: In a basic sense, yes, but not a full-on modeling of the scope's interior (unless it's ABSOLUTELY necessary, then sure) I'm modeling the actual body of the scope itself (I just got a reference photo of an ACOG 4x prior to this comment)

Comment: @Forged-In-Steel so if you are just modeling the scope, do not care about the interior, or looking through it, then why do you need to know how to get a specified magnification effect?

Comment: I guess I worded it wrong... or maybe I took it in the wrong direction. I did want to look through it, granted it looks like I didn't want to. Sorry if this seems roundabout. So basically the full interior is necessary for this, correct?